# PHP: Condition 'if link is clicked' then page is not refreshed

Tags: javascript, php, html, messagebox

I'm writing an exam code when the page is refreshed a next question is loaded.

There are other links on the page if any is clicked a conformation message should appear.

- If `Ok` then go to the linked page.
- If `Cancel` then stay on the same page.

The problem I'm having is that the page gets refreshed and have already loaded another question after the cancel button is clicked.

HTML:

```
<a href="/?link=1" name="link1"> HOME </a>
```

PHP:

```
 if(isset($_GET['link']))
 {
    $link=$_GET['link'];
    if ($link == 1){
        echo "<script>
        var r=confirm('There are no fields to generate a report');
        if (r==true)
        {
           window.location.href='evalhome.php';
        }
        else
        {
           relax();
        }
        </script>";
  }
```

Comment: You have not shown the mechanism for the two events, which is required to answer this question.

Comment: What mechanism? I think that I've provided all the required info.

Comment: Where is the code for your OK and CANCEL buttons?

Comment: it's inside the confirm alert. Thanks for the help the problem is already solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make your links like this :

```
<a href="#" onclick="if(confirm('There are no fields to generate a report')) 
window.location='evalhome.php';else return false;" name="link1"> HOME </a>
```

if user clicks on it, he will see a confirmation, if he press ok, he will be redirected to `evalhome.php` . if not, stays in the same page.

Comment: Thank you so much, appreciate the help.